# Procedure doesn't compile on sys.dba_policies

Tags: oracle, procedure

It is probably an easy mistake but I still can't spot it.
Using my sec_admin schema, I can run the following:

```
 SELECT count(*) FROM sys.dba_policies;
```

Which outputs 1

Now I want to create a procedure using:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE pr_add_policy_row

   IS
   num NUMBER := 0;
   BEGIN
      SELECT count(*)
        INTO num
        FROM sys.dba_policies;

   END pr_add_policy_row;
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Error(6,7): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(8,18): PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to `select` from a table or view within a procedure, you need the `select` privilege `with grant option`. Let the DBA grant you

```
GRANT SELECT ON sys.dba_policies TO user3019499 WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: thanks! May I ask why we have to do this? I want to understand the reason

Comment: Very simple. `with grant option` means that you can forward your privilege to other users. Since you can make your procedure executable to other users, who have no `select` privilege on `sys.dba_policies`, those other users can indirectly get the ability to get data from that table/view from you. Therefore, Oracle requires you to have the `grant option` before you can do that.

Comment: makes a lot of sense, very clear explanation, thanks!

Comment: the DBA did run: grant select on sys.dba_policies to sec_admin with grant option;
I still can't compile the procedure, I'm getting an error. I tried reconnecting

Comment: Very strange. Just tried the same, without a problem :/

Comment: He tried on multiple databases, it worked. It didn't work on Amazon RDS (our database). We'll be contacting them. Thanks for the help!